# How to convert GMT to Local Time using moment in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, format

I'm trying to convert a time in the format of '2019-07-15T08:57:58.749081' to a local time using the format of 'Month Day(th/st) Year Hour:mm am/pm". So anything like "September 9th 2018 9:40 pm" or "July 18th 2019 9:40 pm", etc.

This is to use the moment package imported into a ReactJS app. I can get the format to look right but the time is still GMT/UTC. To do this format I used
var dateTime = moment(param).format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a');

But I really need the formatted time in my own local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input string is in ISO 8601 format, and the time basis is UTC, the string should contain a trailing `Z`.  In other words, it should look like `2019-07-15T08:57:58.749081Z`.  Since it doesn't, you have two choices.

- You can append the `Z` yourself:

  ```
  moment(param + 'Z').format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a')
  ```
- You can parse as UTC and then switch to local mode before formatting:

  ```
  moment.utc(param).local().format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a')
  ```